# Is "Discrete" the correct/best term?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I have a page - similar to a wiki page - that contains descriptive information in paragraph form as well as a side bar with labels bits of information. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle) is a good example, the right size information bar. All the labeled bits of information; could I label that as "Discrete Data" or "Discrete Information"? Is there a more correct term for it?

Comment: I don't see that Discrete as you use it adds any meaning to the word Data or Information, so why add it?

Comment: @Oldcat - I'm looking to differentiate the paragraph descriptive information from the key/value type data. On the page editor I have 2 tabs for editing the different parts of the page. I'm looking for names to put in the tabs.

Comment: The sidebar information for the wiki page is a summary, an overview, or a fact sheet. I think you could the tabs summary/detail, overview/descriptive, or fact sheet/long form.

Comment: What were you thinking of putting in the tab that *wasn't* the sidebar?

Comment: Why not call it *Sidebar*? Or *Tidbits*?

Answer (score 1):

No, "discrete" is not an appropriate description. "Discrete" means:

> [discrete](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discrete) — consisting of or characterized by distinct or individual parts

With regards to *data*, discrete data means data that takes a very specific form:

> [discrete data](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/discrete-data.html) — Data that can only take certain values. For example: the number of students in a class (you can't have half a student).

This is a technical term and it would not apply to your usage.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with MrHen that discrete is not the right term because it has a very technical meaning that your example does not seem to qualify for.

If I had to come up with a title based on your example I would use a term like
*Specification Data* or *Specification Information*.

If you are looking for something shorter maybe the abbreviated *Spec Data* or *Spec Info*.

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722, please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU.